# PHP websockets doesn't works on wss://

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, websocket, ratchet

I moved my site to https://.
On http to sockets there was a connection through ws: //sitename.com: 3003, now it is necessary that they were available on wss: //sitename.com: 3003.
How do I do this?
Thank you.

PHP:

```
$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:3004');
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(3003, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
  new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
      new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
        $pusher
      )
    )
  ),
  $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

JS:

```
window.phpSocket = new ab.Session('wss://sitename.com:3003',
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen   443 ssl;
    keepalive_timeout   70;

    client_max_body_size    500M;
    root /var/www/path/to/site/root;
    index index.php;
    server_name sitename.com;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip            on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript;


    ssl                     on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout     10m;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your nginx conf does not specify how to forward your client wss to your server port listened at 3003.

you should add this to your server block in nginx.conf

```
location /wss/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3003;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

And change your Js code to this:

```
window.phpSocket = new ab.Session('wss://sitename.com/wss/',
```

More info about how to use nginx as a websocket_proxy, please refer to https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/